# Building DAX Gateway Analysis formula

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to build a formula in DAX that will show the number of customers who purchased again after their initial purchase, broken out by Product.  I have a standard data warehouse with a Order Placed fact table, a Customer dimension table, and a Product dimension table.  I am able to find the number of customers who purchased each product on their initial purchase by using this formula:

```
First Purchase Customer Count = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Demand[CustomerKey]),Demand[Customer Order Sequence Number] = 1)
```

My visual is a table with the Product as the only attribute, so this first formula is being calculated per Product.  The next formula needs to count the number of customers who bought a second time, regardless of what Product they purchased that second time, but it should only include customers who purchased the current Product the first time.  I have successfully created this formula to do it, but it usually errors out on the 1M row limit unless I filter the Product by subcategory.

```
Rebuyer Count = COUNTROWS(INTERSECT(SUMMARIZE(FILTER(Demand,Demand[Customer Order Sequence Number] = 1),[CustomerKey]),SUMMARIZE(CALCULATETABLE(FILTER(Demand,Demand[Customer Order Sequence Number] = 2),all('Product')),[CustomerKey])))
```

How can I improve this formula so it will run without bombing?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but on the off-chance that this is still an issue for you, have you reviewed the New and Returning Customers pattern on DaxPatterns.com? http://www.daxpatterns.com/new-and-returning-customers/

Your returning customers solution is creating a table of first-time customers, and then a table of second-time customers, and then joining those two tables together to count the number of first-time customers who are also a second-time customer.

The DaxPatterns solution is slightly different. Rather than calculating 2 potentially large tables of customers on the fly and then joining them, it is counting existing customers who have made a prior purchase.

You would need to adapt their solution to meet your requirements. They have a concept of Absolute Returning Customers (meaning the customer's first-purchase was for any product, and their second purchase was for the specific product you care about). You want the reverse of that (the customer's first-purchase was for a specific product, and their second purchase can be anything).

Overall, however, you'll have less bombing out if you start from a single list of first-time customers and filter out the customers you don't want (i.e. who never bought again) vs. compiling 2 separate lists of customers and intersecting them.

(It's the difference between letting everyone into the theatre, then throwing out everyone without a ticket, vs. checking tickets at the door and only letting people with a ticket in).